# How to validate data copied from one table of a keyspace to a table in a different keyspace in Cassandra?

Tags: validation, cassandra, datastax, cql, cassandra-2.0

We are copying data from a column family in a keyspace to another keyspace in the same Data Centre . And we want to verify whether the cf size or no. of records copied is same as that of the source cf . 
Is there any way to measure  size of cf in entire cluster ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Cassandra does not maintain per table / per cluster row count. In general it depends on your dataset size:

- small dataset: run `select count(*) from <table> limit <max_number_of_rows>`.
- large dataset: write a script using cassandra driver which scans thru the all table (with paging), counting all the rows
- large dataset, 2nd way: use `cqlsh copy` to dump the table to csv file, then count the lines.
- very large dataset: use Spark + Cassandra connector to distribute load among the whole cluster.